# Can you sort an adjacent row to a row you've already sorted, based on that row?

Tags: vba, excel

I have a macro to sort different rows. However, once I sort one row, I want the adjacent data to be sorted within those sorts. The example below will give a good pictorial represenation.

```
1  B
1  A
1  C
1  D
2  A
3  C
3  A
3  B
```

Within each number I want the adjacent row in alphabetical order, thanks!!

Comment: It's not clear from your question why the built-in sort (on the two columns of interest) wouldn't do what you want.

Comment: You sort with a macro? Not by clicking on the first cell in the column and selecting the excel sort? Can you post your vba code, so we can add to it?

Answer (score 0):

You need to sort twice, first on one key and then on the other, BUT on the second sort you must use an algorithm that is stable. Stable sorts maintain order for equal elements.

Its ok to sort both keys with a stable sort (in two passes) but a stable sort may be slower than one that is not. This may matter if you have lots of entries to sort.

[Stable sorts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category%3aStable_sorts)